# Does it exist a free tool to automatically identify db tables used by a java process? Does sonarqube do it?

Tags: casting, sonarqube

I would like to know if exist a free tool to automatically identify/detect db tables used by a java process? Does sonarqube do it? Considering commercial tool, does CAST do it?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such a feature in SonarQube.

Comment: Are you able to tell me if CAST has this feature? I'm quite sure that, in general, there is no tool with this feature. Anyway I need a confirm.

Comment: I'm not a CAST expert but from what I remember, it can provide some data about it. But it is based on string matching and can lead to quite a lot of false positives.

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends of what is your objective. Basically, there could be 2:
1. You want to know which are the tables that are accessed by different Java classes because you need to know which part of the code - in fact, probably code from different applications - could be impacted by a change on the table. This is called 'impact analysis'.
2. You want to know if different Java classes are doing the same statements - update, insert, delete - on the same table. This is duplicate code and this is a bad programming practices.

CAST can do both, but with 2 diffrent tools. Because case #1 can not be automated, you have to do it manually. SonarQube can identify duplicate code and answer to case #2, although they have some plans to do case #1. Maybe end of this year or next year, I don't know really when, and in what extend it could be automated.

Now, you have to understand that impact analysis is a manual process, and can be more or less time consuming, and not completely safefull (I mean, the results could be wrong) depending of a lot of factors, mainly your knowledge of the tool, of how to do a manual impact analysis, and the code - and databases - you have analyzed. For example, you could have a database #1 with a link and a trigger to another database #2 where you are searching for an impact on a table, but if you have not analyzed database #1, well, you missed it.

If you can give me more precisions about you use case, I will be able to answer more precisely your question.

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you for you exhaustive answer. I would like to know if CAST is able to identify tables (used by a java process) in a code written using named query or hybernate.cfg.xml (old way). Futhermore, is CAST able to identify tables in store procedures written in pl-sql. Last but not least, could you please send me some specific link of CAST documentation about these features? THANKS

Comment: Yes to your 2 first questions. Now, as said previously, this is not automated but a manual process. I don't know of any link with documentation, first because Cast will ask you to fill a form and eventually contact you for a demo, 2nd because Cast does not push very much this tool.

Comment: I can send you an image that will help you to understand but I cannot publish it (as this is code from an app). Please contact me (https://www.linkedin.com/pub/jean-pierre-fayolle/1/399/948 for instance) or let me your email. Regards.